# Custom helper within handlebars template

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm new to Handlebars, but trying to use it in a nodejs environment to allow users to design/layout an html email via a template.  Within my code I'm essentially grabbing the user-defined template contents from a file, instantiating Handlebars, compiling their template, and executing the template with certain passed parameter objects.

What I'm struggling with is that I would like the users to be able to add custom helpers to their templates in case they want to do any advanced formatting, logic, etc. - however they don't seem to be working.  Any helpers I've registered within the template itself (via a script tag) inline with the html don't seem to be visible to Handlebars and I get "Missing helper: whatever".  I'm afraid they may have to be pre-defined back in my code where I instantiate Handlebars and compile their template.  Is that the case?  If so, I'm going to have to find a different approach.  I'm hoping maybe there's a way they could be included within the template itself.  Any info would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Handlebars.registerHelper('formatDate', function(date) {
            return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + new Date(date).toLocaleTimeString();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div>{{formatDate "2019-01-01"}}</div>          
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Comment: How do you store the custom helpers?

Comment: They would literally be part of the template just like the one shown above - so stored as a file.  From my continued reading on the subject, I don't believe this is possible with Handlebars because of it's logic-less nature. I was hoping there might be some workaround available when used in non-browser environments such as mine where it really didn't matter, but so far I haven't found anything.

Comment: Are your template functions executed on the client or on the server?

Comment: Well, you have to think of this like a command-line app where the users don't really have the code, they're just running the command and pointing it to their template file. This would all happen on their machine.

Comment: I can't say that I really understand how you intend this to work, but I think you would need to capture the helper function as a string and then `eval` it in JS and pass it in the `options` parameter when invoking the template function.

Comment: Hah, I was just looking at the possibility of trying to extract the javascript from the script tags and eval'ing it prior to executing the template.  I didn't realize I'd have to use the options parameter - good to know.  Thank you!

Comment: @76484 - if you want to post your comment as an answer, i'll mark it so you can get credit.  I think like you said - parsing the custom helper code out of the template and eval'ing it is about as close as you can get.